# C# abstract property that can be initialized in constructor but readonly afterwards?

Tags: c#, inheritance

In a class I have a property

```
protected abstract string test{ get; }
```

When I try to initialize it in a constructor. I get an error saying:

> Property or indexer xxx cannot be assigned to. -- it is read-only.

Is there a way to allow some property to be

1. abstract
2. Read-only after initialization in ctor ?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this thing?  The idea of an abstract property is that you can change its value in the derived class; the idea of a read-only property is that it cannot be changed. Those seem like opposites. What is your use case?

Comment: We want a string to be passed in a derived class ctor to override the base class value, but be const after initialization.

Comment: Then why is the property *abstract*?  Why is it not simply a concrete, readonly, non-virtual property?

Comment: @EricLippert Good suggestion. For my use case your suggestion would get me around the above requirement. Thks!

Answer (score 4):

You likely don't want an `abstract` property. You would only use that if you wanted to force the derived class to provide a custom implementation. In your case you simply want it to be set in the constructor and `readonly`.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected string MyProperty { get; }

    public Base(string myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
        : base("DefaultValue")
    { }
}
```